# Dynamic values in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, where-clause

I am trying to read rows one by one from a table and pass values to the query condition. I am unable to proceed further. do I have to use counter /iteration or is there any options. Any help is much appreciated

I want to pass values into the value like condition

```
create table #temp 
(
     userid int,
     typeid int
)

insert into #temp values (1, 101)
insert into #temp values (1, 221)
insert into #temp values (3, 401)
insert into #temp values (4, 501)
    
create table #target
(
     userid int,
     roleid int,
     value varchar(max)
)
    
insert into #target values (1, 000, 'something here userid:1 typeid:101 something here')
insert into #target values (1, 001, 'something here userid:1 typeid:221 something here')
insert into #target values (1, 001, 'something here userid:1 typeid:331 something here')
insert into #target values (3, 002, 'something here userid:3 typeid:401 something here')
    
    
select t.userid, d.roleid, t.typeid
from #target d
inner join #temp t on t.userid = d.userid
                   and value like '%userid:'t.userid' typeid:'t.typeid'%'
```

This is the result I get:

| userid | roleid | typeid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000 | 101 |
| 1 | 001 | 221 |
| 3 | 002 | 401 |

Comment: @DaleK my apology added ON in the condition and modified the question to be clear. any help is much appreciated

Comment: `and value like '%userid:'t.userid' typeid:'t.typeid'%'` isn't valud SQL either?

Comment: @DaleK that's where i need help on how to change the query or have to change the entire approach

Comment: @DaleK i need roleid, userid, typeid in the results . thats the last query in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236168/discussion-between-rocky3151-and-dale-k).

Comment: Thanks @DaleK updated my question with the result table . hope this is clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you just need to familiarise yourself with the [string concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select t.userid, roleid, typeid
  -- How to debug such a query
  --, [value]
  --,'%userid:' + convert(varchar(32),t.userid) + ' typeid:' + convert(varchar(32),t.typeid) + '%'
  --, case when d.[value] like '%userid:' + convert(varchar(32),t.userid) + ' typeid:' + convert(varchar(32),t.typeid) + '%' then 1 else 0 end
from #target d
inner join #temp t on t.userid = d.userid
  and d.[value] like '%userid:' + convert(varchar(32),t.userid) + ' typeid:' + convert(varchar(32),t.typeid) + '%'
```

Returns

| userid | roleid | typeid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 101 |
| 1 | 1 | 221 |
| 3 | 2 | 401 |